# Cause for 'This endpoint does not support BlobStorageEvents or SoftDelete' in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I am developing a data factory that downloads a csv file from a source and writes it to an Azure Storage account that i have read/write rights on. Everything looks good. it gets validated, but when i (test) run, i keep getting the error:

```
This endpoint does not support BlobStorageEvents or SoftDelete. Please disable these account features if you would like to use this endpoint.\", 409, HEAD
```

I checked; the source and sink are DIFFERENT files on different locations, i do have successfull connection on both endpoints. What else can i check to fix this?

Comment: what is your source ? is it on-premise ? are you using a Copy activity ?

Comment: The source is indeed on-premise and we use a copy action to copy it (from an endpoint) to the blob storage.

Comment: why not trying AZ-Copy ? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-v10

Comment: Maybe using AZ-copy is the solution. i will try that!

Comment: Does your storage account have Heirarchical Namespace enabled? If yes, you should be using Data Lake Gen2 connector. If no, you should use Azure Blob Storage connector.

Answer (score 1):

From the error it seems to be an incorrect storage type. Could you please double check if your storage type is Azure Blob storage or Azure data lake storage gen 2 account? You can go to Storage account Settings and under Configuration section you can find these details. Depending upon version for your storage account you can use the connector for your copy activity in the pipeline. Use Azure Blob Storage connector if your account type is that else use ADLS gen 2 connector if your storage account type is general purpose v2.